# Do i have to install django again when i create a new project directory?

Tags: django, directory, installation

I am setting up a new project. I have installed virtual environment. But Do I have to install django again in that directory??

Comment: no need. Just activate the ENV and use

Answer (score 1):

Each project should have its own, separate virtual environment. Reusing the same virtual environment for multiple projects kind of defeats the whole point of virtual environments.

When you want to **create a new project**, you first create a new virtual environment for it.
A newly created virtual environment is empty, so you have to install Django into it before you can run `django-admin startproject`.

Everytime you want to **run an existing project**, e.g. with `python manage.py runserver`, you first have to activate the virtual environment.

Comment: can I create another project in the same virtual env or is it a bad structure/design?

Comment: Technically, you can, but it is bad design.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need not to install django again. You can invoke the virtual environment again.

If you have installed virtual environment in the project folder and have configured it that way, then you perhaps have to create a new virtual environment.

There are good tools available:

1. [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)
2. [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

A good reference point can be [RealPython](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) for managing different versions of django.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should install Django with every project you start with.